# How does HP make Windows Explorer display a warning when opening the Recovery Drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-explorer, windows-registry, data-recovery

On my HP computer, there is a partition called `D:\Recovery` and it looks like this.

[image: It looks like this.]

When I open it, I get a message inside of the Windows Explorer window saying:

> "This area of your hard drive contains files used during Windows Push Button Reset and HP image recovery. Do not delete or alter any of these files."

[image: It looks like this.]

So I was wondering, how exactly does HP make Explorer display this message?

Is there some sort of special feature in Windows that I don't know about that allows you to map a folder to a picture and message? Is there something in the registry? I am really fascinated by this and have found no resources on the internet pertaining to this. In fact, I don't even know what type of feature this is even called to begin with.

Comment: If you use Process Explorer (Microsoft/Sysinternals), highlight the Explorer.exe process.  Then in the lower pane of Process Explorer, show DLLs and sort by Company Name do you see a module by HP?

Comment: Unfortunately, I accidentally uninstalled the recovery partition and have no way of telling anymore. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP Creates a Windows Explorer Plugin called HPRPGuard.dll under C:\system.sav\Util which is a hidden folder. By using the registry and Desktop.ini files, they can force the Plugin to load. If you want more information I could give more detailed description but it is really complicated to explain.

If you use 7zip to browse to D:\Recovery and rename Desktop.ini to Desktop.ini.old, you should be able to disable that protection on that folder.

I have the source code to the HP Recovery Media Creation. HP doesn't tell people how it works, I had to experiment with it and decompile the scripts for it.

[image: These are the files that allow the recovery protection to work]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in defeating this protection. Simply rename `C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\Recovery\Protect.dll` and the recovery partition will be accessible in explorer.